# How to calculate derivative of moment generating function in python?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, sympy

Here is my code so far, I thought I could use scipy but it doesn't give me the right answer for the second derivative, moment(0, 2). My guess is that I'm not applying scipy.misc.derivative correctly and that I should use diffs_exp from sympy but I couldn't get that to work either..

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np

def mgf(s):
    mu = 2
    sigma = 0.5
    mgf = np.exp(mu*s + ((sigma**2)*(s**2))/2)
    return mgf

def moment(s, i): 
    mo = misc.derivative(mgf, s, dx=0.000000001, n=i)
    return mo
```

moment(s, i) evaluates correctly when i=1 but not when i>1. moment(0,2) should equal sigma^2 or .25 but the function returns 0.0 currently

the function will only be evaluated when s=0, the more important part is that the differentiation is correct.

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives?

Comment: No, I was just looking at the documentation for diffs_exp(): http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/differentiation.html, will give the tutorial a try, thanks!

Comment: Try changing `mgf = ...` to `mgf2 = ...`, likewise for `return mgf`.

Comment: No luck on mgf2 unfortunately

Comment: Please post what you mean to obtain, and what you get, for several values of s.

Comment: As per http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html, `dx` should be `int` (albeit the default is quoted as `1.0`... strange).

Comment: I think that is a mistake, dx=1 is way too large an interval for the correct value to be found for many equations...

Comment: You are missing a term `(mu+s^2)^2*exp()`. Anyway, the result should not be 0.

Comment: I suggest you try identifying the source of error with a simpler function.

Comment: According to sources I'm looking at the mgf is correct above: http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/6normgf.pdf  Where does your missing term come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how one would do it symbolically with `sympy` and numerically evaluate the result for a particular `mu`, `sigma` and `s`

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: mu, sigma, s = symbols("mu sigma s")

In [3]: expr = exp(mu*s+(sigma*s)**2/2)

In [4]: f = lambdify((mu, sigma, s), expr.diff(s, 2))

In [5]: f(2, 0.5, 0)
Out[5]: 4.25
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I confusedly put the answer for the 2nd central moment in my body 4.25 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a good step size for a finite difference scheme is a tricky businness. Too small step and you're doomed because of the round-off error (as you've found). Too large step, and the scheme is too coarse (as you've found as well). `scipy.misc.derivative`'s default step is not very useful, BTW. There is some literature on how to choose a sensible step. Eg, Numerical Recipes has a brief introduction to a simple scheme.

In this particular case finding a sensible step is reasonably easy:

```
In [41]: from scipy.misc import derivative

In [42]: def f(x):
   ....:     arg = 2.*x + (0.5*x)**2 / 2.
   ....:     return np.exp(arg)
   ....: 

In [53]: derivative(f, 0., dx=1e-5, n=2)
Out[53]: 4.2499981312005266
```

An alternative is to use a package which does a smarter step size selection (one keyword for internet/literature searches is Romberg extrapolation). For example, [numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools):

```
In [57]: import numdifftools as nd

In [59]: fdd = nd.Derivative(f, n=2)

In [60]: fdd(0)
Out[60]: array([ 4.25])
```

Answer (score 0):

So I mucked around in the source code after misreading the question in the earlier answer(since deleted).

Scipy misc.derivative calculates second order derivative by default as

lim h->0 (f(x+h)-2*f(x)+f(x-h))/h^2

The problem here occurs because the output of np.exp() is float64, which is of limited precision i.e 52 bits for mantissa and 11 for exponent. When we decrease dx, the difference between the terms occurs in higher order digits, which due to limited precision are not present. On summation this vanishes to zero.

For reference, in the above function, the values are
0.999999998, 1, 1.000000002 for f(x+h),f(x),f(x-h) respectively with x=0 and h =1e-9. The solution could be using either function that have larger precision, but that would involve changing scipy source code and is not a small undertaking.(Python pow functions are not arbitrary precision)

Other(practical) option is to use smaller values for dx. dx=1e-2 seems to actually give close enough answer i.e 4.2501848996 as compared to 4.25 which is the actual second derivative.